# ¿Cómo voy a poder optimizar el algoritmo para encontrar la subsecuencia común más larga (SCL) entre dos cadenas?

Tags: java, algoritmos, optimización

Un algoritmo utilizado para encontrar eficientemente el SCL entre dos cadenas:

1. Defina dos cadenas, cadena1 y cadena2, con longitudes m y n, respectivamente.
2. Cree una matriz 2D, dp, con dimensiones (m+1) x (n+1). Inicialice todos los elementos de dp a 0.
3. Itere sobre los caracteres de cadena1 de izquierda a derecha (i) y cadena2 de arriba a abajo (j).
4. Si cadena1[i] es igual a cadena2[j], incremente dp[i+1][j+1] en 1. Esto significa que los caracteres actuales coinciden y la longitud del SCL que termina en este punto es uno más que el SCL termina en los personajes anteriores.
5. Si cadena1[i] no es igual a cadena2[j], tome el valor máximo entre dp[i][j+1] y dp[i+1][j] y guárdelo en dp[i+1][j +1]. Esto significa que los caracteres actuales no coinciden, por lo que la longitud del SCL que termina en este punto es la máxima del SCL que termina en los caracteres anteriores en cadena1 o cadena2.
6. Después de iterar sobre todos los caracteres, el valor de dp[m][n] será la longitud del SCL entre cadena1 y cadena2.
7. Para recuperar el SCL real, comience desde dp[m][n] y retroceda a través de la matriz dp. Si cadena1[i-1] es igual a cadena2[j-1], agregue el carácter al SCL y muévase en diagonal a dp[i-1][j-1]. De lo contrario, muévase hacia la izquierda si dp[i][j-1] es mayor que dp[i-1][j], o muévase hacia arriba si dp[i-1][j] es mayor.
8. Repita el paso 7 hasta llegar a la esquina superior izquierda de la matriz dp.

Siguiendo este algoritmo, la subsecuencia común más larga entre dos cadenas se puede encontrar en programación.

Un ejemplo de código Java:

```
public static String repeatCharacter(char ch, int length) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        sb.append(ch);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
char ch = 'X';

System.out.println("Enter size of first string");
int m = myObj.next();
String string1 = repeatCharacter(ch, m);
System.out.println("Enter size of first string");
int m = myObj.next()
String string2 = repeatCharacter(ch, n);
String lcs = "";

System.out.println("Enter first string");
string1 = myObj.nextLine(); 
System.out.println("Enter second string");
string1 = myObj.nextLine(); 
int dp[m+1][n+1];
int i, j;

for (i = 0; i < m + 1; i++) {
     for (j = 0; j < n + 1; j++) {
          dp[i][j] = 0;
     }
}

for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
     for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
          if (string1[i] = string2[j])
              dp[i+1][j+1]++;
          else
              dp[i+1][j+1] = Math.max(dp[i][j+1], dp[i+1][j]);
     }
}

i = m, j = n;
while (i > -1 && j > -1) {
    if (string1[i-1] = string2[j-1]) {
        lcs = lcs + string1[i-1];
        i--;
        j--;
    }
    else if (dp[i][j-1] > dp[i-1][j])
        i--;
    else
        j--;
}
```

Sin embargo, la utilización de bucles for anidados va a poder tomar O (m n) tanto en el tiempo como en el espacio.

¿Cómo voy a poder optimizar la complejidad del tiempo y la complejidad del espacio de este algoritmo?

<sub>Traducción del [inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77808341/how-can-i-optimize-the-algorithm-to-find-the-longest-common-subsequence-lcs-be)</sub>

<sub>[Traducción en portugués](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/590502/como-vou-a-poder-otimizar-o-algoritmo-para-encontrar-a-maior-subsequ%c3%aancia-comum)</sub>

Comment: ¿Y lo que has realizado es...?

Comment: @fredyfx Estoy yendo a buscar otro algoritmo aún mejor.

Comment: Pedir "un mejor algoritmo" y poner el enunciado, suena a tarea académica y sin esfuerzo (código de tu parte), las chances de recibir respuesta, son bajas. Por otro lado, ¿Cuáles son tus criterios? ¿mejor en qué sentido? Tal cual está la pregunta, que no te sorprenda que le den negativos y/o te la cierren (en los 3 sitios tienes negativo). Para evitar eso, realiza la implementación en algún lenguaje de programación, coloca los casos, las métricas que tienes, los errores que hay, las entradas y las salidas que esperas, teniendo eso, es probable que alguien te de una mano. Saludos.

Comment: Debes poner lo que has intentado para que se te pueda ayudar

Comment: Tanto como si las subsecuencias no deben obligatoriamente ser caracteres consecutivos (NP-Hard) como si deben serlo, es imposible hacerlo en tiempo lineal y mucho menos en tiempo constante. A lo sumo podría optimizar se algo el uso de memoria. Si alguien puede resolverlo en O(n) que le den el premio Turing.

Comment: Yo te puedo ayudar pero yo programo en C#, así que añade la etiqueta c# en tu publicación si lo deseas

Comment: @Japv podrías hacer otra pregunta en el sitio acerca de como convertir el código que hagas a Java y así llevarte el bounty... Ya tu sabe mentalidad de tiburón :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código que compartes no solo no compila... puede ser optimizado fácilmente poniéndolo en métodos.

Primero en vez de leer el tamaño de las cadenas y después las cadenas puedes directamente leer las cadenas y obtener el tamaño de las cadenas leídas.

```
Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter first string");
String string1 = myObj.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter second string");
String string2 = myObj.nextLine();
findLCS(string1, string2);
```

Después podemos observar que tienes un problema de índices en tu while:

```
while (i > 0 && j > 0) {
```

es la versión correcta debido a que no podemos usar índices negativos para las cadenas y 0 es el índice de la primera posición.

Después tu código tiene un pequeño problema que es que no imprime resultados...

```
System.out.println("Longest Common Subsequence: " + lcs);
```

Esto nos dejaría un código como el siguiente:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter first string");
        String string1 = myObj.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter second string");
        String string2 = myObj.nextLine();
        findLCS(string1, string2);
    }

    private static void findLCS(String string1, String string2) {
        int m = string1.length();
        int n = string2.length();

        StringBuilder lcs = new StringBuilder();

        int[][] dp = new int[m + 1][n + 1];
        int i, j;

        for (i = 0; i < m + 1; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < n + 1; j++) {
                dp[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (string1.charAt(i) == string2.charAt(j))
                    dp[i + 1][j + 1]++;
                else
                    dp[i + 1][j + 1] = Math.max(dp[i][j + 1], dp[i + 1][j]);
            }
        }


        i = m;
        j = n;
        while (i > 0 && j > 0) {
            if (string1.charAt(i - 1) == string2.charAt(j - 1)) {
                lcs.insert(0, string1.charAt(i - 1));
                i--;
                j--;
            } else if (dp[i][j - 1] > dp[i - 1][j])
                i--;
            else
                j--;
        }

        System.out.println("Longest Common Subsequence: " + lcs);
    }

}
```

Desde allí ya podemos empezar a optimizar por ejemplo mediante:

- Utilizar solo un arreglo unidimensional dp en lugar de una matriz 2D para almacenar los valores dinámicos.
- Utilizar variables prev y temp para almacenar temporalmente los valores anteriores necesarios durante el cálculo del arreglo dp.

La complejidad de tiempo sigue siendo `O(m*n)`, ya que todavía necesitas recorrer ambas cadenas pero los resultados son infimamente mejores, por ejemplo con el caso mostrado en [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence) de las cadenas ABCD y ACBAD ya nos dará el resultado correcto.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter first string");
        String string1 = myObj.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter second string");
        String string2 = myObj.nextLine();
        findLCS(string1, string2);
    }

    private static void findLCS(String string1, String string2) {
        int m = string1.length();
        int n = string2.length();

        int[] dp = new int[n + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            int prev = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                int temp = dp[j + 1];
                if (string1.charAt(i) == string2.charAt(j)) {
                    dp[j + 1] = prev + 1;
                } else {
                    dp[j + 1] = Math.max(dp[j], dp[j + 1]);
                }
                prev = temp;
            }
        }


        int length = dp[n];
        char[] lcsChars = new char[length];
        int i = m, j = n;
        while (i > 0 && j > 0) {
            if (string1.charAt(i - 1) == string2.charAt(j - 1)) {
                lcsChars[--length] = string1.charAt(i - 1);
                i--;
                j--;
            } else if (dp[j] > dp[j - 1]) {
                i--;
            } else {
                j--;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Longest Common Subsequence: " + new String(lcsChars));
    }

}
```

Y hasta allí puedo ayudarte... entiendo que puedes usar otras cosas más locas como un [búffer circular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) para ayudarte a optimizar aún más el código.